# Язык C, WriteFile(), Windows

Tags: c, windows

Не совсем понимаю, как WriteFile() работает с файлами (не перекрывающийся вывод).

В msdn написано, что функция в случае успеха возвращает TRUE. Так же там написано, что в четвертый параметр записывается кол-во действительно записанных байтов (простите за каламбур).

При работе с последовательными портами было проще. Если WriteFile завершилась, то это связано либо с ошибкой, либо с истечением установленного таймаута записи. Соответственно было ясно, что если функция вернула TRUE, то все в порядке, а если записались не все данные, то их можно дописать.

1) Допустим, мы пишем в файл, функция возвращает FALSE, - все ясно, произошла ошибка. Но не ясно, чего ожидать в четвертом параметре. Какие-то данные могли записаться в файл? Или там будет 0? И что делать, если какие-то данные все же записались?

2) Допустим, мы пишем в файл, функция возвращает TRUE, снова не ясно, чего ожидать в четвертом параметре. Могла ли функция записи в файл завершиться успешно, но при этом занести в файл 99 байт, а не 100?

Я так понимаю, что для записи в файл при использовании WriteFile() нужно действовать так же, как при записи в сокет? Делать цикл, пока все данные не запишутся, либо не произойдет ошибка?

Еще в msdn написано, что левые процессы могут блокировать часть файла, и в этом случае WriteFile() завершится с ошибкой... Плюс, есть мнение, что WriteFile() может завершиться из-за прерывания или переключения контекста.

Какая-то мутная тема, помогите разобраться.

Comment: После вызова WriteFile ничего не проверяется, и, файл может быть даже ещё и не записан на диск. Однозначно записан после Flush. Для разрешения конфликтов такого рода - используются блокировки файла. Ещё нужно понимать, что диск - блочное устройство, и запись идёт блоками по 4К. Если две программы пишут в разные блоки - будет всё ок. Если в одинаковые - кто-то может кого-то перетереть.

Comment: Про буферы системы и диска я знаю. Меня интересует, как возвращаемое функцией значение TRUE-FALSE коррелирует с поведением четвертого параметра - количеством действительно записанных байтов.

Comment: Да, если ф-ция вернула FALSE  - точно ничего не записано. 0 байт.

Comment: А относительно блокировки части файла - такое возможно не только при записи из двух процессов/потоков. Такое возможно из-за дефрагментации, а так же из-за антивируса и пр. Но мой файл открывается без шаринга, поэтому, я думаю, можно быть уверенным хотя бы в том, что никакой процесс не заблокирует часть моего файла, пока он открыт.

Comment: Абсолютно точно? Я не смог найти на msdn этой информации.

Comment: Для синхронной записи - точно. И для асинхронной тоже, сообщение о записаных байтах прийдет в асинхронной позже.  msdn: *Return Value Nonzero indicates success. Zero indicates failure. To get extended error information, call* т.е. FALSE  - сбой.

Comment: Окей. Если функция вернула FALSE, значит записалось 0 байт. А если вернула TRUE, то можно попытаться дописать, если записалось не все?

Comment: Можно. А если запись завершится из-за прерывания, то возвращается FALSE и код ошибки ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED

Comment: Если FALSE, то чего можно ожидать в 4 параметре? 0 или не 0?

Comment: Можно ожидать, что изменений не будет, я обычно присваиваю ноль до вызова функции, что б не было коллизий. Если ноль не присвоите - можно получить что угодно.  Мусор туда точно ф-ция не записывает.

Comment: В msdn написано, что функция пишет в четвертый параметр ноль до выполнения каких-либо действий. Значит мусора там оказаться не может. Но где есть официальная информация по тому, что пишется в 4 параметр, если функция завершится с ошибкой или без таковой?

Comment: @Максим Как Вы собираетесь использовать эту информацию, если вызов был неудачен? Получается что-то вроде - `-Сходи, возьми у той компании рублей пятьсот... Ну что, дали? -В морду дали.-А рублей-то сколько?`